# What is the reaction mechanism of nitrogen leaving from diazo compounds?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, carbocation, nucleophilic-substitution

When a diazo compound is formed, and then a nucleophile is added to the mixture. Will nitrogen gas leave first or will the nucleophile have to "do" a substitution reaction? What I mean is will the carbocation be formed due to nitrogen leaving or will it be an S<sub>N</sub>2 reaction? Or will it depend on the carbon that the diazo group is attached to, (like primary, secondary, etc.) depending on the stability of carbocation formed? In short, I mean to ask if it's S<sub>N</sub>1 or S<sub>N</sub>2.

Is it a thumb rule that when an unstable diazo compound is formed, that the nitrogen leaves without any nucleophile intervention?

Comment: Because when I asked it to my professor, he said its a MUST Carbocation forming reaction (he didn't specify sn1... even though i asked him that if it is sn1...), however he is not someone i can trust THAT much.. Thanks:D

Comment: Probably depends a bit on the reaction. A real chemist would probably check kinetics of the reaction to see if it's first order in the nucleophile or not.

Comment: @Zhe Maybe a real physical chemist would. A real organic chemist would run with whatever they get out.]

Comment: @Jan fair point and important missing qualifier..

Answer (score 3):

The reaction is $\ce{S_N1}$

> [image]
>
> Among the evidence for the $\ce{S_N1}$ mechanism with aryl cations as
>   intermediates, is the following:
>
> 1. The reaction rate is first order in diazonium salt and independent of the concentration of Y.
> 2. When high concentrations of halide salts are added, the product is an aryl halide but the rate is independent of the concentration of the
>      added salts.
> 3. The effects of ring substituents on the rate are consistent with a unimolecular rate-determining cleavage.
> 4. When reactions were run with substrate deuterated in the ortho position, isotope effects of $\sim 1.22$ were obtained. It is
>      difficult to account for such high secondary isotope effects in any
>      other way except that an incipient phenyl cation is stabilized by
>      hyperconjugation, which is reduced when hydrogen is replaced by
>      deuterium.
>
> [image]
>
> 5. That the first step is reversible cleavage was demonstrated by the observation that when  $\ce{Ar^{15}N+ #N}$ was the reaction species,
>      recovered starting material contained not only $\ce{Ar^{15}N+ #N}$ but
>      also $\ce{ArN^{+} #N}$This could arise only If the nitrogen breaks
>      away from the ring and then returns. Additional evidence was obtained
>      by treating $\ce{PhN+ #N^{15}}$ with unlabeled $\ce{N2}$ at various
>      pressures. At $\pu{300 atm}$, the recovered product had lost $3 \%$ of
>      the labeled nitrogen, indicating that $\ce{PhN2+}$ was exchanging with
>      atmospheric $\ce{N2}$

---

**Source**: March's Advanced Organic Chemistry: Aromatic Substitution: Nucleophilic and Organometallic

Comment: What if it was a aliphatic diazonium compound ( i am aware that its unstable but assume it to be kept at a certain temp where its stable). Will it still remain SN1 or will it depend on the substrate?

Comment: @Cinnamaldehyde yes, you are right they are unstable hence, immediately nitrogen gas is given off and a planar carbocation is formed which reacts via $\ce{E1}$ or $\ce{SN1}$